# Twisted python3 обмен данными client <- -> server

Tags: python, python-3.x, сервер, клиент-сервер, twisted

Я являюсь новичком в Twisted, а так же в построении связей между client <--> data <--> server. При создании просто сервера, который я пытаюсь связать с приложением на Kivy я столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

Для реализации связи между клиентом и сервером обязательно понадобится передача между ними файлов, а так же данных, более сложнех, чем просто строка. И на этом этапе я сел в лужу. Я совершенно не представляю, каким образом осуществляется данный процесс.

По моей первичной задумке я собираюсь передавать между сервером и клиентом хотя бы какие-то объекты, которые должны будут быть обработаны на сервере и возвращены в клиент. Как пример, это будет сортировка массива на стороне сервера и его возврат в приложение. Вопрос состоит именно в том, каким образом я могу транслировать на сервер для обработки условный атрибут приложения и вернуть его так же в виде атрибута того же класса.

Макет "сервер - клиент" выглядит следующим образом. В нём не столь важен Kivy, сколько именно передача данных, между двумя приложениями.

```
# server.py

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen

class EchoServer(protocol.Protocol):
    # Основной протокол подключений

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        response = self.factory.app.handle_message(data)
        print(response)
        if response:
            self.transport.write(response)

    # Функция, которой я хочу добиться из приложения
    def return_sort_array(self,array):
        return array.sort()

class EchoServerFactory(protocol.Factory):
    protocol = EchoServer

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app




class SM(ScreenManager):
    # Инициализация виджета manager
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SM, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class TwistedServerApp(App):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        App._running_app = self
        super(App, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.built = False
        self.root = None


    def build(self):
        reactor.listenTCP(8000, EchoServerFactory(self))
        return SM()

    def handle_message(self, msg):
        msg = msg.decode('utf-8')
        return msg.encode('utf-8')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TwistedServerApp().run()




# client.py




from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
from kivy.support import install_twisted_reactor

install_twisted_reactor()



class EchoClient(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
    # В это вникать не стоит. Просто вызов on_connection функции.
        self.factory.app.manager.ids.Server_Screen.on_connection(self.transport)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
    # Тоже вникать не стоит. Отправка сообщения на сервер.
self.factory.app.manager.ids.Server_Screen.send_message(data.decode('utf-8'))


class EchoClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = EchoClient

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app


class SM(ScreenManager):

    # Инициализация виджета manager
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SM, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class Server_Screen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Server_Screen,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def send_message(self, *args):
        msg = "I'm work!"
        self.connection.write(msg.encode('utf-8'))

    def on_connection(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection
        self.new_array = [-20,1,32,41,92,51,-492,-5,9]
        self.send_message()


class ClientApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.connect_to_server()
        return SM()

    def connect_to_server(self):
        reactor.connectTCP('localhost', 8000, EchoClientFactory(self))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ClientApp().run()
```

Сам Kivy не играет роли в данном случае. Важен именно способ передачи условного массива new_array на сервер, где к нему будет применен sort() и возвращен обратно. Как я понял, метод write() передает именно строку на соответствующую функцию на сервере. А возня с eval(),exec(), etc.. не особо устраивает. Особенно учитывая, что ожидается передача целых классов.

Буду крайне признателен, если объясните, как получить на сервер этот массив в виде атрибута класса, а не в виде строки, и после в таком же виде вернуть его обратно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На транспортном уровне все данные, передающиеся по сети - это байты. Twisted, как и любой другой сетевой фреймворк, передаёт и принимает байты. Соответственно, ваша задача - преобразовать используемые структуры данных в поток байт и обратно. Проще всего это сделать сериализацией в [JSON](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON):

```
import json

from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet import reactor


class SorterProtocol(LineReceiver):
    def lineReceived(self, line):
        # Декодируем байты в строку
        s = line.decode()
        # Десериализуем строку в список
        items = json.loads(s)
        # Сортируем список
        items.sort()
        # Сериализуем список в строку
        s = json.dumps(items)
        # Кодируем строку в байты
        response = s.encode()
        # Отправляем обратно
        self.transport.write(response)


class SorterFactory(Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return SorterProtocol()


reactor.listenTCP(1234, SorterFactory())
reactor.run()
```